# Why my sqlserver procedure cannot output %

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql statement below but it does not work. The error msg is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.". I found when I remove '%', it works as it should but I need to output '%' in this sql, can someone provide me with some suggestions?

```
declare @per varchar(10) = '0.00%'
set @str = 'select ' + @per + ' AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;
exec (@str)
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you execute is:
`select 0.00% AS ColumnA from #TempSui'`, you need to add quotes:

```
'select ' + QUOTENAME(@per, '''') + ' AS ColumnA from #TempSui'
```

Comment: it's worth noting that `QUOTENAME` will take care of escaping single quotes within the value too, unlike naive concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just miss the quotes

```
declare @per varchar(10) = '0.00%'
set @str = 'select ''' + @per + ''' AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;
exec (@str)
```

It is not a bad idea to use `PRINT` when you debug a dynamic TSQL:

```
print @str
```

Will give :

```
select '0.00%' AS ColumnA from #TempSui
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use parameters.  Then you wont' have this problem:

```
declare @per varchar(10) = '0.00%'
set @str = 'select @per AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;

exec sp_executesql @str, N'@per varchar(10)', @per=@per;
```

Voila!  No issues at all.  And, your code is safer and might be more efficient too (no need to recompile every time it is run).